# Parse JSON in websocket sharp

Tags: json, websocket-sharp

I'm trying to parse JSON string that received from websocket sharp but keep failing.

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket(WebAddr))
{
    ws.Log.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
    ws.OnOpen += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\log.txt", "connected!");
    };
    ws.OnMessage +=  (ss, ee) =>
    {
        JsonValue jo = JsonValue.Parse(ee.Data);
        string value = (string)jo["levelid"];
        Console.Write(value + '\n');
    };
}
```

It just threw exception error when reaches `string value...` part.

I'm using `System.Json` from nuget.

Comment: show your json string and exception

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The server will respond with 2 messages, one is Json object and one is Json array.

dynamic jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ee.Data);

This fixed my problem!